# How to access fields of case class from JSP?

Tags: scala, jsp, jstl, el, case-class

When I was a Java programmer my typical approach was to write a POJO with getters and access its fields in JSP through those getters `${pojo.field}`.

Now I'm trying to use Scala. Case classes looks like a good replacement for POJO's, but scala provides `field()` getters instead of `getField()` which is required by JSP.

So, how to access case class fields from JSP without manually writing `def getField = field` for each field? Or maybe there are something more suitable approach for my purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotate the fields of your case classes with [scala.beans.BeanProperty](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.beans.BeanProperty):

```
import scala.beans.BeanProperty;

case class Person( @BeanProperty val name : String, @BeanProperty val age : Int);
```

Now your person class will have methods like `getName()` and `getAge()` as well as `name()` and `age()`.

If you need bean setters, use `var`s:

```
class Person( @BeanProperty var name : String, @BeanProperty var age : Int);
```

(Note: I generally don't like to make nonimmutable objects case classes, even though it would be legal to declare `case` before the mutable class declaration.)

Now you'll find that the equivalents of java `void setName( String name )` and `void setAge( int age )` have been defined.

Comment: The only disadvantage is that I need separately annotate every field although I just want all field to be bean properties.